# Sql Server remote connection fails

Tags: sql-server

I have configured a windows10 PC as Sql data server. The pc have static/real IP. I can ping the ip from other pc using internet connection. But, I can't connect sql server from remote pc. I have enabled TCP/IP from SQL Server Configuration Manager. Also disabled the firewall. But still can't connect. Could you please help me.

Comment: *I have enabled TCP/IP from SQL Server Configuration Manager* You need to restart the instance after changing this.

Comment: Yes, I restarted the instance and later the PC too. But did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to Setting Open Port SQL 1433

[open Port 1433](http://itproguru.com/expert/2011/06/how-to-open-firewall-port-1433-for-sql-server-database-engine-for-use-with-scom-or-anything-else-2/)

and then re-Check with

[check open Port](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)